# Why is my uiview showing a border when i screenshot it

Tags: ios, objective-c

//Screenshot Code

```
/* Capture the screen shoot at native resolution */
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(Grid.frame.size, Grid.opaque, 1.0f);
[Grid.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

/* Render the screen shot at custom resolution */
CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0 ,0 , Grid.frame.size.width * 4, Grid.frame.size.height * 4);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cropRect.size, Grid.opaque, 1.0f);
[screenshot drawInRect:cropRect];
customScreenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

/* Save to the photo album */
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(customScreenShot,self, @selector(thisImage:hasBeenSavedInPhotoAlbumWithError:usingContextInfo:), NULL);
```

When ever I use this it outlines my uiviews in gray but if I use the manual screenshot by holding the power and home button at the same time these gray outlines do not appear.

Can anyone Help?

Comment: The title and body are giving conflicting reports, but either way, the desired behavior is not described, which leaves this question a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have only integer **non-fractional dimensions** (42.000 or 1337.000, not 42.500 or 1337.1234). This can be the source of your display problem

```
//using ceil to round the values to integer non-fractional dimensions
    self.messageLabel.frame = CGRectMake(ceil(self.messageLabel.frame.origin.x),
                                         ceil(self.messageLabel.frame.origin.y),
                                         ceil(self.messageLabel.frame.size.width),
                                         ceil(self.messageLabel.frame.size.height));

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.messageLabel.bounds.size, self.messageLabel.opaque, 0.0f);
    [self.messageLabel.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.messageLabel.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];
    UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```